# Converting to mp4 from mjpg video stream

Tags: java, video-streaming, ip-camera, mjpeg

I am trying to capture the live streaming from ip camera into vlc player .The problem is ,its looking for a source file like .mp4 etc but the stream that i want to show in it is just a http stream which is on the URL http://192.168.x.x:80/video.cgi/mjpg Can anybody help how to convert mjpg stream to mp4 using java  ??

Comment: There is a java API to vlc: http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/ Maybe it provides a wrapper to http streams.

Comment: i am using vlcj ...not able to find a way to play the stream in player ..